# How to set up a mail server correctly?

Tags: setup, mail-server

I have read a number guides on setting up a mail server, but none of them seems to work completely.

### My Requirements:

- I want to send and receive mails to and from all domains. (i.e., yahoo,gmail,aol,etc.)
- I only need real system users.

### Note:

- I am running Ubuntu server edition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo tasksel install mail-server
```

That will give you a fully functional mail server with sane defaults.

For more information on how to set up a more customized solution, refer to the following resources:

- [Ubuntu Server Guide on E-Mail Services](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/email-services.html)
- [Setting up an Ubuntu System as an Email Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer)