# How to set up a mail server?

Tags: server, mail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up a mail server correctly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51887/how-to-set-up-a-mail-server-correctly)

I wanted to send and receive emails as `my-custom-name@my-mail-server-com`; How can I setup it up under Ubuntu.

I have dyndns setup on my machine.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer