# how to config postfix when send email need login?

Tags: 12.04, email, postfix

how to config postfix when send email need login? I have config postfix server to send email to my customers. I found postfix can send mail without login. I doubt it might be used for other ones send spam email, so who can help me?

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
#delay_warning_time = 4h
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
myhostname = domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = domain.com, localhost
#mydestination = hash:/etc/postfix/mydomains
relayhost =
relay_domains = gmail.com,hotmail.com,163.com,qq.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination,reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_invalid_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unauth_destination,reject_unknown_sender_domain,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,permit
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    permit
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_client_restrictions = sleep 1,reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium

#authorized_submit_users = bitwolaiye
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain, login
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand the question. Are you trying to send mail from a system connected to a dynamic IP address? Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/91839/how-to-send-e-mail-from-ubuntu-server/91857#91857

Comment: It is almost identical to [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/458909/spam-issues-while-using-postfix-as-a-two-way-relay/458917#458917) question. I have answered there.

Comment: @Christopher I have a static IP server, I use it as smtp server, but I found it can sendmail without login, so I want postfix check login before sendmail.

Comment: @JohnSiu I have try your answer , but I can sendmail without login also.

Comment: Update your question with /etc/postfix/main.cf. I think your config is too wide open. Especially "mynetwork".

Comment: @JohnSiu I have paste my cf in question content, can you help find where is the problem. Thx.

Comment: Are you testing from the email server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `main.cf`. Test from a machine other than the email server.

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
#delay_warning_time = 4h
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
myhostname = domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = domain.com, localhost
#mydestination = hash:/etc/postfix/mydomains
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unlisted_recipient,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
        permit

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    permit
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_client_restrictions = sleep 1,reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium

#authorized_submit_users = bitwolaiye
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain, login
```

Comment: oh,yes. I think 'reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org' is usefull.

Comment: You can add more. But test frequently. They die from time to time and will really screw up.