# sending e-mail with my ip using wget

Tags: scripts, mail, wget

I have a computer that every 5 hours change is IP 
I want to make a script that will run every hours with this command -

```
wget -q -t 5 --output-document=- "http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp"
```

and send me the ip that he is getting.
how do I do this?
and is it possible to do?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the remote system can [send mail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91839/how-to-send-e-mail-from-ubuntu-server/91857#91857). Create a script in cron's hourly folder.

```
sudo -e /etc/cron.hourly/ipcheck
```

The contents of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
wget -q -t 5 --output-document=- "http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp" | mailx -s "External IP Address" me@mydomain.com
```

Set the script to executable:

```
sudo chmod 0755 /etc/cron.hourly/ipcheck
```

Comment: thanks , where\how do I write this??          , in which language is it?

Comment: @david Um... `sudo -e` invokes the default editor that will create a new file (ipcheck) in the /etc/cron.hourly/ directory. It's a BASH shell script.

Answer (score 0):

use crontab

```
 crontab -e
```

and then add below lines

```
 MAILTO="your@emailaddress"
 0 * * * * wget -q -t 5 -O - "http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp"
```