# How can I use Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS as a mail server to be able to retrieve emails using MS outlook as the client?

Tags: mail-server

I want to create a mail server using Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS, but need to be able to retrieve emails using MS outlook as the client.

I have a spare PC which I am going to install Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS. How do I go about configuring it to be a mail server, and I specifically need to be able to retrieve email using MS Outlook on another Windows 7 PC. Both PC and server will be on the same LAN/Network.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mail Transfer Agent (MTA). Here is a nice guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer

Just saw, there is another good post on it on this forum: [how-to-set-up-a-mail-server-correctly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51887/how-to-set-up-a-mail-server-correctly?rq=1)